# Zend Framework error : Resource Matching "Jquery" not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm facing the following error after I deployed my application to my ubuntu server:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 
'Resource matching "Jquery" not found' in /home/ZendFramework-1.12.7/library/Zend/Application
/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:706
```

I have tested my code on local and it works fine but it does not on the server. I'm using ZendFramework-1.12.7 and I'm not able to figure out what the problem is.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

**Update:**

My application.ini has the following configuration related to jquery:

```
resources.Jquery.enable = true
resources.Jquery.ui_enable = true
resources.Jquery.noconflictmode = false
resources.Jquery.render_mode = 255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

I copied the zend library from my system onto the server and changed the include_path to the new library in php.ini file and everything started working. I think there was some compatibility issues when I used another version of zend library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pluginPaths.ZendX_Application_Resource = "ZendX/Application/Resource"
resources.jquery.enable = true
resources.jquery.ui_enable = true
resources.jquery.noconflictmode = false
resources.jquery.render_mode = 255
```

Note: now `J`query is `j`query

Available resource plugins are listed here. Jquery is zend extra

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html